# Zend Coding Standard in Netbeans

Tags: zend-framework, netbeans, coding-style, netbeans-6.9, phpcodesniffer

How to configure Netbeans PHP to follow Zend Coding Standard?

I'm struggling with this quite a while, and still get phpcs errors on multi line function arguments.

Would you share your settings?

Comment: I'm not relying on NetBeans to do the code formatting for me, but maybe you should vote on the following ticket that was opened : http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=188785.

Comment: @wimvds Already got my vote, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its in options. Tools > Options > Editor > Formatting And then select PHP from languages.

Comment: You basically explained how to go to the PHP formatting options, but the original question was about how to configure these PHP formatting settings in NetBeans to support the Zend Coding Standards:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.html